# Add the "Return" value to a div

Tags: php

I am wondering if it's possible to get the return value in PHP added to the page content, and not just showing as an error.

Currently, when the form is submitted it generates this:

[image]

What I want is that when the form is submitted and the error/success message is to show, the content of the page should be there aswell. Like this:

[image]

This is my code:

```
if($_POST)
{
    $newTopic = $forum->newTopic();


        /*
         * Return codes:
         * 1: No title
         * 
         * 100: Success
         */

    switch($newTopic)
    {

            case 1:
                $error = 'You have not entered any title.';
                $stop = true;
            break;

            //If no error = success.    
            case 100:
                $success = "Success! TOpic created";
            break;
    }

    die($error);
}
```

How can I obtain this?

**EDIT:**

The HTML for the page is generated like this:

```
loadmodule('forum');
$forum= new Forum;

if(file_exists(HEADER)) { include_once(HEADER); }
if($contents) { print $contents; }  
if($_POST)
{
    $newTopic = $forum->newTopic();


        /*
         * Return codes:
         * 1: No title
         * 
         * 100: Success
         */

    switch($newTopic)
    {

            case 1:
                $error = 'You have not entered any title.';
                $stop = true;
            break;

            //If no error = success.    
            case 100:
                $success = "Success! TOpic created";
            break;
    }

    die($error);
}


if(file_exists(FOOTER)) { include_once(FOOTER); }
```

Comment: Don't use `die` then. You have to output the same page again and add the error message to one of the elements.

Comment: in fact, don't use die() at all. You should only use die() to abnormally terminate the script. PHP ends the script process automatically when it reaches the end. Just `echo` or `print` the data, after sending the headers (http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: Well, how are you creating the HTML for the page?

Comment: @FelixKing I've updated my question with how the HTML is generated.

Comment: Where is the HTML of the form? In any of the included files?

Comment: if($contents) { print $contents; }  that is how the html is generated. I have to write $contents.="my html here";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, use `echo` instead of `die`. Please read the introduction in the PHP manual. `echo` is literally the *first* word in PHP you ever learn.

Comment: But if I write echo($error) at the bottom, it still just print the error message at the bottom of the page. I need a way to get it into the actual site content.

Comment: @oliverbj: Please read the PHP manual. It explains all of what you want plus plus simply and extensively. I will not start explaining trivial things that you can read in the manual.

Answer (score 1):

You can update the same page with new echo statement. Say in the end of the page remove the die() and add an echo(). In this echo statement you can show the response in what ever format you want. Load the same page which you are currently using to enter the values instead of any other error page to show the error message.

Comment: But if I write echo($error) at the bottom, it still just print the error message at the bottom of the page. I need a way to get it into the actual site content.

Comment: Is this PHP code not in the site contents page ? Where is this PHP code is it in the site contents or anywhere in the server side.

Comment: Here is a quick working code, not in php but in java. There is home.jsp which is used to input data similar to yours. when the request is servered in doPost(), update the status like this:      >request.setAttribute("statusMessage","No value entered");      >String homeURL = response.encodeURL("home.jsp");
>RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher(homeURL);
>rd.forward(request, response);                                         This will redirect the response to the home.jsp which is the original page. The main page will read the attribute"statusMessgae" and can show the message.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
$newTopic = $forum->newTopic();


    /*
     * Return codes:
     * 1: No title
     * 
     * 100: Success
     */

switch($newTopic)
{

        case 1:
            $mssg = 'You have not entered any title.';
            $stop = true;
        break;

        //If no error = success.    
        case 100:
            $mssg = "Success! TOpic created";
        break;
    }


 }
 ?>
 <html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div>
    <p><?php if(!empty($mssg)) echo $mssg;?></p>
 </div>
 <div>
   ------------------
   -----------------
</div>
</body>
</html>
```